# Spy on exported function in smart component

Tags: reactjs, sinon, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test that dispatch calls the correct function in my smart component. However I only achieved to test the return value of that function. Is it possible to mock, spy or stub the function?

my component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchDocumentsIfNeeded } from '../actions';
import SearchComponent from '../components/Search';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        triggerSearch: (event) => {
            dispatch(fetchDocumentsIfNeeded(event.target.value));
        }
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchComponent);
```

My test so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import Search from '../../src/containers/Search';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {spy} from 'sinon';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const mockStore = configureMockStore();

describe('containers/Search', () => {
    let wrapper, store;

    beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore({searchedText: "fun"});
        store.dispatch = spy();
        wrapper = shallow(<Search store={store} />);
    });

    it('maps triggerSearch to dispatch search action', () => {
        const event = {target: {value: "test"}};
        wrapper.props().triggerSearch(event);

        expect(store.dispatch.calledWithMatch({text: "test", type: 'SEARCH_DOCUMENTS'})).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

```
import dependency from '../../src/actions';

jest.mock('../../src/actions', () => ({
    fetchDocumentsIfNeeded: jest.fn()
}));

expect(dependency.fetchDocumentsIfNeeded).toBeCalled();
```